# R programming (beginner): Combining two lists--> dataframe -> csv

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried to combine two lists into one dataframe:

```
all_stas <- list()
for(i in vid_id){
  stas <- get_stats(video_id = i)
  all_stas <- rbind(all_stas,stas)
}
View(all_stas)

all_detail <- list()
for(i in vid_id){
  detail1 <- get_video_details(video_id = i)
  all_detail <- rbind(all_detail,detail1)
}
View(all_detail)


df <- data.frame(all_stas,all_detail)
write.csv(df, file = "new_file.csv")
```

Afterwards I would like to store it into a csv file.

When I run it it gives me the following warning message

```
Warning message:
In rbind(all_stas, stas) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

Does anyone of you know how I can make the code work?

Comment: Which line is giving you this error? what does running "str(all_stas)" and "str(all_detail)" report? Those should be the same before rbinding.
And do you have test data to show/re-create example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block below is triggering an error

```
all_stas <- list()
for(i in vid_id){
  stas <- get_stats(video_id = i)
  all_stas <- rbind(all_stas,stas)}
```

If I understand your code correctly you can get around that error by

```
 all_stas <- list()
        for(i in vid_id){
                all_stas[[i]] <-  get_stats(video_id = i)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it in the code. It does work for the view(all_stats). Do you know what the best way is to make a dataframe out of it afterwards?

Comment: do.call(rbind, all_stas) will giver you a matrix that you can convert to a data.frame